# MySQL: Select rows that are in a date range of each other

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have a MySQL like the following:

```
Events
+----+------+--------------------------------+
| id | name | sites_id | created             |
+----+------+--------------------------------+
| 1  | test | 1        | 2013-11-01 00:00:00 |
| 2  | test | 1        | 2013-11-02 00:00:00 |
| 3  | test | 2        | 2013-11-13 00:00:00 |
| 4  | test | 3        | 2013-11-14 00:00:00 |
| 5  | test | 4        | 2013-11-25 00:00:00 |
+----+------+----------+---------------------+
```

What I want to select events that are created with in 48 hours of each other and have the same site id. (in this example I would expect ids 1 and 2).

Any help at all would be appreciated as I have drawn a blank how to do this solely in SQL.

Thanks

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Comment: What if you have a "chain" of events within 48 hours, but not all within 48 hours? E.g. 11-01, 11-02, 11-03, 11-04, 11-05. What do you expect then?

Comment: Hi Bart, No it doesn't have to chain.

Comment: @OliverRidgway then where do you start?

Comment: @OliverRidgway: can you provide a sample output that you want with your sample data?

Comment: @OliverRidgway: create a sample table with sql fiddle :http://www.sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: Personally, I wouldn't attempt to solve a problem like this inside of the database. I would use a scripting language, and run a query for each event to find any events in range. This obviously will not scale well and the table in question will grow by ~10,000 rows a month. I just wondered if anyone out there knew of a way to do this inside of MySQL, who may have had a similar problem before.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT e1.*
FROM events e1
INNER JOIN events e2 ON e1.sites_id = e2.sites_id
  AND e1.id <> e2.id
WHERE ABS(datediff(e1.created, e2.created)) <= 2;
```

<kbd>[sqlfiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f0969/8)</kbd>

This gives you the result:

```
ID  NAME    SITES_ID    CREATED
2   test    1           November, 02 2013 00:00:00+0000
1   test    1           November, 01 2013 00:00:00+0000
```

Comment: Thanks Filipe, this is the most concise

Answer (score 3):

I've not syntax checked this (so see it as more of a guideline):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.id
    , t1.name 
    , t1.sites_id 
    , t1.created
FROM
    Events t1
    INNER JOIN Events t2
        ON (t2.created BETWEEN DATE_ADD(t1.created, INTERVAL -2 DAY) AND DATEADD(DAY, INTERVAL 2 DAY))
        AND t1.sites_id = t2.sites_id
        AND t1.id <> t2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

There you go:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE table.created > DATE_SUB(table.created, INTERVAL 48 HOUR) GROUP BY sites_id HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem: `select events that are created with in 48 hours of each other`  You selected events within 48 hours of now.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
Select m.id,m.created from TPS_info m, tps_info c 
where c.created between m.created AND date_add(m.created, INTERVAL 43200 MINUTE)
group by m.id,m.sites_id
```

SQL fiddle:http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bce0c/2

Comment: @Oliver Ridgway: updated my post. and it is working perfectly fine. Also includes fiddle demo link.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem, `select events that are created with in 48 hours of each other and have the same site id`